# Can I "combine" 2 regex with a logic or?

Tags: regex

I need to validate Textbox input as credit card number. I already have regex for different credit cards:

- Visa: `^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$`
- Mastercard: `^([51|52|53|54|55]{2})([0-9]{14})$`
- American Express: `^3[47][0-9]{13}$`

and many others.

The problem is, I want to validate using different regex based on different users. For example: For user1, Visa and Mastercard are available, while for user2, Visa and American Express are available. So I would like to generate a final regex string dynamically, combining one or more regex string above, like:

```
user1Regex = Visa regex + "||" + Mastercard regex

user2Regex = Visa regex + "||" + American Express regex
```

Is there a way to do that? Thanks,

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You did not state your language but for whatever reason I suspect it's JavaScript. Just do:

```
var user1Regex = new RegExp('(' + Visaregex + ")|(" + Mastercardregex + ')');
// or if es6:
let user1Regex = new RegExp(`(${Visaregex})|(${Mastercardregex})`);
```

This simply combines the two patterns with a pipe `|` character, which indicates alternative matches. Each pattern is also wrapped in parentheses to group them.

You can also use `(?:)` for speedier execution (non-capturing grouping) but I have omitted that for readability.

Comment: +1 for `(?:)` which works with `(?:foo|bar)` for logical or with strings | multiple chars characters

Comment: I tested this, and `Visaregex` needs to be sliced or else the slashes will get included literally into the combination. in other words if `Visaregex == /ab+c/` and `Mastercardregex == /de+f/` then `user1Regex` would end up being `/(\/ab+c\/)|(\/de+f\/)/`, not `/(ab+c)|(de+f)/` like we wanted. So I would change your answer to: `let user1Regex = new RegExp(\`(${Visaregex.toString().slice(1,-1)})|(${Mastercardregex.toString().slice(1,-1)})\`);`.

Comment: To get rid of the beginning and ending slashes and potential modifiers use `new RegExp('(' + Visaregex.source + ")|(" + Mastercardregex.source + ')');`

Answer (score 11):

Use the | operator and group all with parentesis ()

```
^(4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|([51|52|53|54|55]{2})([0-9]{14})|3[47][0-9]{13})$
```

If all regex are correct it should work

Answer (score 3):

Not sure which language you are using to implement but you can use a single `|` to use a logical or most regex. My suggestion would be to store each regex as a string and then concatenate and compile when necessary.

in python it would be something like

```
visa = "visa_regex"
mastercard = "mastercard_regex"
combined = re.compile(visa + "|" + mastercard)
```

Answer (score 1):

combine two expressions or more, put every expression in brackets, 
and use: `*?`

This are the signs to combine, in order of relevance:

*? example 1 : `(A)*?(B)`

| example 2 : `A|B`

()() example 3 : `(A)(B)`

()|() example 4 : `(A)|(B)`