# Notepad++ search with a logical AND

Tags: regex, notepad++

Using Notepad++ I need to find lines that would contain 2 keywords (both).

I've found [how to combine 2 regex with a logical 'or' operator.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947561/can-i-combine-2-regex-with-a-logic-or)

**Example:** `(searchword1)|(searchword2)`

But how do I combine with logical 'and'?

Tried &, &&.. no success.

**Example of input:**

```
The CAT goes up and down the ROAD.
The CAT goes up and down the CITY.
```

**Search words:** `CAT & ROAD`

**Expected result:** line1

Comment: What would a matching text be like?

Comment: Give us some examples of potential matches and attempts.

Comment: @ihtus ofcourse there is no `&` operator. The context is a bit vague. I mean what exactly is a line ? Is a line that ends with `\r?\n|$` or with `[.?!]` ? Anyways, you might use recursion `(?m).*?(CAT|ROAD).*?(?!\1)(?1).*`, see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/tG3nQ6)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Find -> Regular expression, then type

```
(CAT)(.*?)(ROAD)
```

Comment: This doesn't match a line, although I don't blame you since the OP didn't show exactly the expected results ...

Comment: you're right, it only points lines that met specified pattern. Since he's trying to FIND these lines - this simple regexp will do

Comment: guys, it's working. Why you expected it will not work?

Comment: @ihtus *sigh* it's *really* tiresome when people don't put clearly the expected output. What is a line ? You said `Expected result: line1`. What is `line1` ? Is it `CAT goes up and down the ROAD` or `The CAT goes up and down the ROAD.` ? There are so many possibilities that this became like a "guess game".

Comment: @ihtus because it's not pointing out the WHOLE line, only the part that starts with CAT and ends with ROAD. For your purpose it's ok, but if you'd like to use this regexp in js code, you wouldn't get the whole line as a result.

Comment: And this answer only matches if the word `CAT` comes before the word `ROAD`..  ie, It wouldn't match - `On the ROAD was a CAT.`

Answer (score 9):

If you are looking for a true `&&` operation where a line contains both words in any order then you will want to match both of these lines:

> The CAT goes up and down the ROAD.
>
> The ROAD goes up and down the CAT. (poor cat)

In this case you will want to use:

```
^(?=.*\bCAT\b)(?=.*\bROAD\b).*$
```

Explanation:

- `^` start line
- `$` end line
- `?=` positive look ahead
- `\b` word boundary. Not sure if you want this or not. Remove these if you want to match any part of word, e.g. `TheCATgoes up and down theROAD`.

`(?=)` is a positive look ahead. We have two such look aheads, one for anything (`*`) followed by CAT and one for anything (`*`) followed by ROAD. There is an implied `&&` between the two lookaheads - both conditions must be satisfied.

Read up on lookarounds **[here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)**

Comment: If I am correct, the best way is to combine both of variants into one via OR operator: `(CAT)(.*?)(ROAD)|(ROAD)(.*?)(CAT))`

Answer (score 0):

A simple pattern if only two words are wanted would use the **or** operator to search for the words in either order:

```
(CAT.*ROAD)|(ROAD.*CAT)
```

For more than two words the positive lookahead is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition to @acarlon answer, which is the one that worked for me.

To make this work in notepad++ you must make sure you have selected the "matches newline" checkbox as well as the Regular expression mode:

[image]